# Stroke appears bigger and bigger each time circle icon scale is reduced

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, icons, google-maps-markers

I create a new map with zoom equals 4:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9526, -98.5795),
    mapType: 'terrain'
  });
```

I listen for the zoom_changed event so that I can redraw my markers with a new scale:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    $log.debug("zoom: " + zoom);
```

and I create my new icon here:

```
 var greenMarkerIcon = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: "green",
      strokeWeight: 1,
    scale: map.getZoom()
  }
```

When I zoom in, everything looks lovely.   The icon grows bigger in scale as I drill down.  Zooming out is where the problem is:

[Click here for image of icon after reducing scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekbj9.png)

The border of the circle becomes bigger and bigger.  I've added a debug statement for the icon.strokeWeight property and it remains 1 the entire time. I'm blowing away all of my old markers and redrawing them again, so I don't know why the single marker strokeWeight is appearing bigger.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that would change the size of the icon (or effect the stroke).  Are you sure you are changing the icon and not just overwriting it with a new one (if the new one is larger, you wont be able to see the smaller one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to change marker icon scale on map zoom and the marker should be smaller/bigger without changing the stroke. Then you need to change only icon scale and set it to the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  console.log("zoom: " + zoom);
  greenMarkerIcon.scale = (zoom + 1) * scale; // +1 is for avoiding zoom=0, scale is initial scale of icon
  marker.setIcon(greenMarkerIcon);
});
```

check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/dUMFW/108/

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided is correct.

I found out what I was doing wrong.  I was creating a new marker each time the user clicked a zoom button.   Markers should be created only once and the associated icon should be changed on zoom.

Thanks.